# Request never returns when upload request size is greater than 4 MB in ASP.NET MVC 5.1/IIS?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7.5, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I have created a very simple ASP.NET MVC 5.1 app with IIS on Windows 7. I have a very simple form and controller. I know the default request limit in ASP.NET is 4MB. But when I upload file(s) greater than 4 MB. My request will never ever return. Tested on Chrome, Firefox and IE. Actually my controller break-point never hit. I think something wrong inside ASP.NET MVC async. Here is my html form,

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Product", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
       <input type="file" id="files" name="files" placeholder="Title" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg" />
}

public async Task<ActionResult> Add(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
```

**Update:** On Chrome I am seeing this continuously.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set **maxAllowedContentLength** on your web config.

like this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
          <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="900000000" />
          </requestFiltering>
     </security>
</system.webServer>
```